# Magical Record with AFIncrementalStore

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, afincrementalstore

I have been wondering how would the life look like If I was to combine AFIncrementalStore and Magical Record. I just don't know how do I set the incremental store as a store for magical record. Does any one know how to perform such operation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is no different with or without MagicalRecord. This is a general Core Data scenario. Once you have your AFIncrementalStore set up and registered, just call

```
-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]
```

you read the Core Data [docs for this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/addPersistentStoreWithType%3aconfiguration%3aURL%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) for more info.

MagicalRecord, when you use the build in stack helpers, you can then use [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultCoordinator] to get the instance of the coordinator to which you want to attach the store.